# Elliptic regularity Neumann problem in non-Lipschitz domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open connected domain of $\mathbb R^3$ with polyhedral, but not Lipschitz in general, boundary. Let $f\in L^2(\Omega)/  \mathbb R$. We consider the following. Find $\varphi:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta\varphi = f \quad\text{in}\;\Omega,\\
\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial n}=0\quad\text{on}\;\partial\Omega,
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
which, in variational form, reads as follows. Find $\varphi\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v = \int_{\Omega} f v\qquad\forall\ v\in H^1(\Omega).
\end{equation*}
Can I conclude that there exists $C>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\|{\Delta \varphi\|}_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C \|f \|_{L^2(\Omega)}?
\end{equation*}
In general, which is the ''smaller'' Sobolev space to which $\varphi$ belong?

Comment: You have $\|\Delta \phi\|_{L^2}=\|f\|_{L^2}$ by definition. Is your question if you can bound $\|D^2 \phi\|_{L^2}$ in terms of $\|f\|_{L^2}$?

Comment: @MaoWao What do you mean by definition? By Definition, I just know that $\Delta\varphi\in \left(H^1(\Omega)\right)'$

Comment: You have $\Delta \phi=f$ in the sense of distributions.